# Dynamic population of select dropdown

Tags: ajax, json, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I searched for previous answers for the same problem but none of them helped me so creating a new question

I am trying to populate a second dropdown list depending on the value of first dropdown list

below is my code

Controller

```
<?php

class ExprResultsController extends BaseController {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish to use controllers instead of, or in addition to, Closure
    | based routes. That's great! Here is an example controller method to
    | get you started. To route to this controller, just add the route:
    |
    |   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
    |
    */

    public function bartExperRsltDwnld()
    {
        return View::make('hello');
    }

        public function soExperRsltDwnldPg()
    {
            $tasks = Tasks::lists('taskname', 'id');
            return View::make('dashboard.admin.exprRslts.exprRsltsSo')
                    ->with('tasks', $tasks);
    }

        public function getExprIds($id) {

        $exprs = Experiments::where('expertype', '=', $id)->lists('expername', 'id');
        /*$options = array();

        foreach ($exprs as $expr) {
            $options += array($expr->id => $expr->expername);
        }*/
        //Response::eloquent($exprs->get(array('id','name')));
        //return Response::json($options);
        return $exprs;

    }

}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('dropdowns/exprs/{id}', 'ExprResultsController@getExprIds');
```

Blade page:

```
@extends('dashboard.dashboard_admin')

@section('page-content') 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header"><i class="fa fa-archive fa-fw"></i> Download Experiment's Data</h1>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('taskname', 'Tool/Task Name:') }}            
            {{ Form::select('expertype',array('default' => 'Please select one option') + $tasks,'default', array('id' => 'expertype')) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('expername', 'Experiment Name:') }} 
            <select class="form-control" id="exprid" name="exprid" ></select>

        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox">Disabled Checkbox
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
            <a href="{{URL::to('dashboard')}}" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
        </div>

    {{ Form::close() }}
   </div> 
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
<br>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i> Note
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Current version only supports capability to download experiment data via excel spread
            sheet. To download first select task type and then corresponding experiment.
            Future versions will support advanced reporting framework.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#expertype").change(function() {

            $.getJSON("/dropdowns/exprs/",{ id : $("#expertype").val()}, function(data) {

                var $exprid = $("#exprid");
                $exprid.empty();

                $.each(data, function(id, expername) {                    
                    $exprid.append('<option value="' + id +'">' + expername + '</option>');
                });
            $("#exprid").trigger("change"); /* trigger next drop down list not in the example */
            });
        });
    });
</script>

@stop
```

Please help me find what is going wrong. When i type the route in the browser it shows me values in DB like this 
{"rbFkbjdmSt":"expr1"}

I tried to put alert inside the  $("#expertype").change(function() and it works. But when i put alert inside $.getJSON("/dropdowns/exprs/",{ id : $("#expertype").val()}, function(data) {
there is no response.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call is failing because the url it is requesting is not correct.  Your route is defined to look for the id as a url segment, but your ajax call is passing the id in as a query parameter.  So, instead of requesting `dropdowns/exprs/{id}`, your ajax call is requesting `dropdowns/exprs/?id={id}`.  This, in turn, returns a 404, and your success callback is not called.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("/dropdowns/exprs/"+$("#expertype").val(), {}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I just tried above approach but did not help..console.log does not show anything. And dropdown is also not populated :( anyother idea to resolve this..

Comment: Hi Guys thank you for the help..both answers are correct however I was facing a different problem. I am new to php, laravel and JS..and did not realize that URL in  $.getJSON("/dropdowns/exprs/"+$("#expertype").val(), function(data) { needs to point to my controller it actually resolved to http://localhost/dropdowns/exprs/BART and not to this http://localhost/rdm_toolkit/public/index.php/dropdowns/exprs/BART. So to fix the problem I changed .getJSON to  $.getJSON("{{url('/')}}"+"/dropdowns/exprs/"+$("#expertype").val(), function(data) {...Hope this helps for future newbies!

Answer (score 0):

**1) First Issue - Controller Methods:**

Thy shall always place a single uppercase character after the HTTP verb in the method:

**Wrong:** `public function getExprIds($id) {`

**Correct:** `public function getExprids($id) {`

**2) You want JSON data, you generate JSON data:**

```
public function getExprIds($id) {

    $exprs = Experiments::where('expertype', '=', $id)->lists('expername', 'id');
   //Convert Illuminate collection to JSON
    echo $exprs->toJson();

}
```

**3) You get JSON data, you work with JSON data:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#expertype").on('change',function() {
        //Expecting an id after '/exprs', as per your route configuration
        $.getJSON("/dropdowns/exprs/"+$("#expertype").val(), function(data) {

            var $exprid = $("#exprid");
            $exprid.empty();
            //We loop through rows of data
            $.each(data, function(index, itemData) {
                //Access to columns is as follows: itemData.ColumnName                    
                $exprid.append('<option value="' + itemData.id +'">' + itemData.expername + '</option>');
            });
        $("#exprid").trigger("change"); /* trigger next drop down list not in the example */
        });
    });
});
```